# Small Error with login

Tags: php

I downloaded a script online for a basic system that will make a user login with  username of admin and password admin, 
But the script has a small error with the login page it seems there a variable that is not declared, I can see the variable is not declared from the form but I can’t declare in a way that can make it work. I need a way to declare the $position variable from form input, so it works well with login.php
Here is the error

**Notice: Undefined index: position in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.3\www\preenrolmentsystem\login.php on line 20
The source has 2 pages one for login.php
And one for the form namely formform.php**

here is login.php

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['position'])) {
    //do something with position
} else {
    //position was not set, maybe give it a default value and use that
}
    //Connect to mysql server
    include('connect.php');

    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    //Sanitize the POST values
    $login = clean($_POST['id']);
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);
    $position = clean($_POST['position']);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE idnumber='$login' AND password='$password'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
        $position = $row['position'];
        }
    if ($position=='admin')
    {
        //Create query
        $qry="SELECT * FROM admin WHERE idnum='$login' AND password='$password'";
        $result=mysql_query($qry);
        //while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    //  {
    //  $level=$row['position'];
    //  }
        //Check whether the query was successful or not
        if($result) {
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                //Login Successful
                session_regenerate_id();
                $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
                session_write_close();
                //if ($level="admin"){
                header("location: admin/index.php");
                exit();
            }else {
                //Login failed
                header("location: loginform.php");
                exit();
            }
        }else {
            die("Query failed");
        }
    }
    if ($position=='student')
    {
        //Create query
        $qry="SELECT * FROM prereg WHERE idnumber='$login' AND password='$password'";
        $result=mysql_query($qry);
        //while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    //  {
    //  $level=$row['position'];
    //  }
        //Check whether the query was successful or not
        if($result) {
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                //Login Successful
                session_regenerate_id();
                $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
                $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['idnumber'];
                session_write_close();
                //if ($level="admin"){
                header("location: student/profile.php");
                exit();
            }else {
                //Login failed
                header("location: loginform.php");
                exit();
            }
        }else {
            die("Query failed");
        }
    }
    if ($position=='Casher')
    {
        //Create query
        $qry="SELECT * FROM casher WHERE idnumber='$login' AND password='$password'";
        $result=mysql_query($qry);
        //while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    //  {
    //  $level=$row['position'];
    //  }
        //Check whether the query was successful or not
        if($result) {
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                //Login Successful
                session_regenerate_id();
                $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
                $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['idnumber'];
                session_write_close();
                //if ($level="admin"){
                header("location: casher/index.php");
                exit();
            }else {
                //Login failed
                header("location: loginform.php");
                exit();
            }
        }else {
            die("Query failed");
        }
    }
    if ($position=='teacher')
    {
        //Create query
        $qry="SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE idnumber='$login' AND password='$password'";
        $result=mysql_query($qry);
        //while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    //  {
    //  $level=$row['position'];
    //  }
        //Check whether the query was successful or not
        if($result) {
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                //Login Successful
                session_regenerate_id();
                $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
                $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['idnumber'];
                session_write_close();
                //if ($level="admin"){
                header("location: teacher/index.php");
                exit();
            }else {
                //Login failed
                header("location: loginform.php");
                exit();
            }
        }else {
            die("Query failed");
        }
    }

?>
```

and loginform.php

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();

    //Unset the variables stored in session
    unset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']);
    unset($_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']);
    unset($_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME']);
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>

</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.ed{
border-style:solid;
border-width:thin;
border-color:#00CCFF;
padding:5px;
margin-bottom: 4px;
}
#button1{
text-align:center;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
border-style:solid;
border-width:thin;
border-color:#00CCFF;
padding:5px;
background-color:#00CCFF;
height: 34px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainwrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <img src="images/amuni.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="loginform.php">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="pre_reg.php">Student Pre Registration</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="help.php">Help</a>
                </li>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="padding:20px; text-align:justify; font-family:arial;">

        <form action="login.php" method="post">
        I.D. Number<br>
        <input type="text" name="id" class="ed"><br>
        Password<br>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="ed"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" id="button1">
        </form>
</div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

plz give a sample declaration for the $position variable and how i cn use it on both files

Comment: I suggest you take any "login" script that, 1) uses the `mysql_` functions, and 2) assumes a cleartext password, and throw it out.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden text in your form with the name `position` so you can access it on PHP.

```
<input type="hidden" name="position" value="somevalue">
```

Comment: it works now Shankar but the page is empty

Comment: Are you passing the proper value for the position variable , something like `admin` or `student` etc from the form.